# is there a way to calculate Matching Distance for categorical variables?

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried Gower's Distance to measure the distance. Though the code is working, however I realized that the approach is not feasible as this algorithm uses the concept of Manhattan distance for continuous variables and dice distance for measuring similarity between Binary variables. Hence, I would need to carry out one-hot encoding for all the categorical variables (with >2 categories), i.e. convert all those into dummy variables.

However I do not want to follow the one-hot encoding approach. I am trying an alternative approach which I am not able to research. Is there a better algorithm?

Below is the dataset:

```
{'Sex': {0: 'Female',
  1: 'Female',
  2: 'Female',
  3: 'Female',
  4: 'Male',
  5: 'Male',
  6: 'Female',
  7: 'Female',
  8: 'Female',
  9: 'Male',
  10: 'Male',
  11: 'Female',
  12: 'Female',
  13: 'Female',
  14: 'Female'},
 'City': {0: 'Lagos',
  1: 'Lagos',
  2: 'Tokyo',
  3: 'London',
  4: 'Tokyo',
  5: 'Lagos',
  6: 'Cairo',
  7: 'Lagos',
  8: 'Lagos',
  9: 'Tokyo',
  10: 'Houston',
  11: 'New York',
  12: 'Lagos',
  13: 'Paris',
  14: 'Chicago'},
 'Region': {0: 'Africa',
  1: 'Africa',
  2: 'Asia Pacific',
  3: 'Europe',
  4: 'Asia Pacific',
  5: 'Africa',
  6: 'Africa',
  7: 'Africa',
  8: 'Africa',
  9: 'Asia Pacific',
  10: 'Americas',
  11: 'Americas',
  12: 'Africa',
  13: 'Europe',
  14: 'Americas'},
 'Graduated': {0: 'No',
  1: 'Yes',
  2: 'Yes',
  3: 'No',
  4: 'Yes',
  5: 'Yes',
  6: 'Yes',
  7: 'No',
  8: 'Yes',
  9: 'Yes',
  10: 'No',
  11: 'Yes',
  12: 'No',
  13: 'Yes',
  14: 'No'}}
```

And the code I implemented:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import gower

df=pd.read_csv("k_mode_data.csv")

distance_matrix = gower.gower_matrix(df)

cat_df = pd.DataFrame(distance_ma
```

trix)

Comment: Why exactly you don't want to use one-hot encoding? It usually works with a cosine_similarity as a metric. Check the Cramers'V, though your case doesn't look usual for this metric.

Comment: As the data I shared is just a sample. I got a huge volume of dataset and doing one-hot encoding will be computationally expensive

Comment: If you are afraid that OHE will lead to unreasonably big number of features, I would suggest to apply any of dimensionality reduction algorithms (e.g. Truncated SVD) after OHE.

Comment: Computing a distance for categorical data is not trivial. As in your case the data is not ordinal (you cannot arrange the categories in an increasing or decreasing order that makes sense) you cannot use just any metric. Instead, OHE seems to be appropriate in this case.

See: https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/